# Can anyone suggest solution for page scrolling with arrow-keys in firefox, when modal is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a webpage, that opens a absolute modal-like-dialog on button click. As the basic, i append 
`body { overflow:hidden; }` 
using jQuery to prevent background page scroll. this works with everything and prevents scroll with mouse. (FF and Chrome - both)

Issue comes with FF when I press arrow keys on keyboard. Page scrolls. (tho it doesn't show scrollbars.) Does anyone face the same problem or Is this a known bug? I would like if anyone can suggest CSS only solution.

Comment: try html { overflow:hidden; }

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. See, overflow with body works perfect - it disables scroll bars so user can not scroll with mouse. Problem is with arrow keys in FF only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent default behavior of arrow keys with JavaScript:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (
        event.keyCode === 37 ||
        event.keyCode === 38 ||
        event.keyCode === 39 ||
        event.keyCode === 40
    )
    {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was expecting a CSS hack if there is any.. but anyway.. work gets done..